# Shading in area between f = 1 and g = |x|

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$\begin{aligned}
        \color{blue} f(x)& \color{blue}=1\\
        \color {red} g(x)& \color{red}=|x|
    \end{aligned}$}
]

\addplot [
    name path = A,
    domain=-2:2, 
    color=blue,
]
{1};

\addplot [
    name path = B,
    domain=-2:2, 
    color=red,
]
{abs(x))};

\addplot [
    pattern=north west lines,
]
fill between [
    of=A and B,
    soft clip={domain=-1:1}
];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which I aim to shade in an area confined between

```
f(x) = 1
```

and

```
g(x) = |x|
```

However, what appears instead is:
[image]

The graph is drawn but the area isn't shaded in. I've tried switching out the two functions with alternative ones and it works, so I'm not too certain what the issue here is. (I am using ShareLaTex)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(For the record: With the release of PGFPlots v1.16 your example gives the expected result. But there is a better/easier way to achieve what you want.)*

Instead of using `domain` use `split` which gives you 3 segments which can be handled individually. So give the general option not to fill anything (`fill=none`) and then state to to the "`segment no 1`" style the fill pattern you want. (The segments start counting with 0, that is why number 1 is the one you need/want here.)

```
% used PGFPlots v.1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        patterns,
        pgfplots.fillbetween,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel={
                $\begin{aligned}
                    \color{blue} f(x)& \color{blue}=1\\
                    \color {red} g(x)& \color{red}=|x|
                \end{aligned}$
            },
        ]
            \addplot [
                name path=A,
                domain=-2:2,
                color=blue,
            ] {1};

            \addplot [
                name path = B,
                domain=-2:2,
                color=red,
            ] {abs(x)};

            \addplot [
                fill=none,
            ] fill between [
                of=A and B,
                % --------------------------------------
                % the below code is what I have changed
                split,
                % draw only selected ones:
                % every segment no 0/.style: invisible
                every segment no 1/.style={
                    pattern=north west lines,
                },
                % every segment no 2/.style: invisible
            ];

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 1):

I would consider this to be a bug (or at least an unexpected behavior) in the `fillbetween` library of `pgfplots`. Note, this is just my personal view as a user, it might be that there is a specific reason why it behaves that way.

Consider the example below, where I stripped out all the parts that are not necessary to reproduce this behavior. As in your example, the area isn't filled. However, if you just comment out the `axis lines=middle` line, the area will be filled as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    domain=-2:2,
]

\addplot[name path=A,color=blue]{1};
\addplot[name path=B,color=red]{abs(x))};
\addplot[black] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=-1:1}];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bad result]
[image: good result]

There seems to be a problem handling the point `0` when you have `axis lines=middle` enabled. A simple workaround is to use one `fill between` from `-1:0` and a separate one from `0:1`. Alternatively, use the `split` method proposed by Stefan Pinnow.

```
\addplot[pattern=north west lines] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=-1:0}];
\addplot[pattern=north west lines] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=0:1}];
```

[image: result with workaround]

Comment: There is indeed a bug that is already reported as [bug 111 in the PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/111/), but has a little different cause than you have thought. The problem **always** shows up when `soft clip` is used and the filled area touches or crosses the axis boundaries -- regardless of the `axis lines` value; i.e. you can also reproduce this with the boxed plot and setting `ymin=0` or lower.